# Do multiple 'helper' classes conflict with the accepted Apple design scheme?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, design

I have a social location based application and I'm in a bit of design conflict that I can't seem to solve or find good information on.

Realizing that I have multiple controllers that will similarly access the user's location and load an array of places to be displayed in a table view, I've made a class that has class methods to provide the users location (coordinates and/or reverse-geocoded address), and populate a variably sized NSArray of locations, and other methods that different controllers will use to form their data. Call it `SpotsManager`.

Anticipating future complexity, I have separated `SpotManager`s duties into 2 separate classes, a `SpotLocationManager` for wrapping a `CLLocationManager` and a `SpotNetworkManager` for wrapping AFNetworking.

Do all of these managers give off code smell? It seems excessive, especially compared to most of Apple's sample apps but at the same time, it also seems like beneficially strict organization.

To contrast my previous approach, I've branched and made a `SpotsList` class that knows how to populate its instances with locations. But I question extending this class without creating some God-class. (And `[SpotList currentCoordinate]` doesn't sound right.)

I realize high level design questions provide an opportunity for opinions, so I am specifically asking for an answers that will provide some objectivity and insight into Apple approved design.

Comment: That's definitely not anything that risks rejection, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: I know Apple wouldn't deny the app, but they usually have a ~way~ of doing things and the reasons are usually pretty relevant. Besides that, I'm interested in the eventual pitfalls of both the examples I listed.

Comment: Can you please explain purpose of CLLocationManager and SpotNetworkManager. What do they do and what types of objects do they return?

Comment: @CodeWorks SpotLocationManager's duties are to provide a simple one line APIs to the user's current coordinates, keeping track of when the user is X distance from the previous coordinate request and so on. The network manager would use this information to send requests to my server and return an array of places to be displayed in a table view.